# Turning strings into integers from a mixed, nested list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I need to turn certain values from a nested list of strings into integers and find the average of them for a programming assignment.

The list looks like this:

```
[['Ty', 'Cobb', '178', '65', '934'], ['Chipper', 'Jones', '4532', '873', '32']]
```

I've tried using for loops to turn them into integers but it returns TypeErrors or empty brackets.

Comment: If you want help with your homework, at the very least please show your attempts. That will give us a better idea of where you are at.

Comment: Please share what you tried so we can fix it and tell you what's wrong

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The format of the data suggests to me that it's something like a CSV where the first two columns are the player names and the remaining columns are scores, and that the ultimately desired result might be to preserve the names along with the average of the associated scores.

Operating under that assumption, I might convert it into something like this:

```
>>> data =  [['Ty', 'Cobb', '178', '65', '934'], ['Chipper', 'Jones', '4532', '873', '32']]
>>> from statistics import mean
>>> {' '.join(d[:2]): mean(map(int, d[2:])) for d in data}
{'Ty Cobb': 392.3333333333333, 'Chipper Jones': 1812.3333333333333}
```